# Best way to Pivot/Rotate Data Set

Tags: python, pandas

I've got the following data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ '1': ['Mon (07/08)','Sales', '2'],
                     '2': ['Mon (07/08)','Stock','3'],
                    '3': ['Mon (07/08)','Qty','4'],
                  '4': ['Tue (08/08)','Sales', '4'],
                     '5': ['Tue (08/08)','Stock','5'],
                    '6': ['Tue (08/08)','Qty','6']})

df
```

[image]

I'm trying to get the following output though would appreciate if you can suggest anything I should look at to get the following output

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the transpose, then use [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to reshape.  After that, it's just a matter of formatting the axes with [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html).

```
# reshape
df = df.T.pivot(index=0, columns=1, values=2)

# format axes
df = df.rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, 1)
```

The resulting output:

```
            Qty Sales Stock
Mon (07/08)   4     2     3
Tue (08/08)   6     4     5
```

Comment: How would I amend this if I've got other columns for example Product Name and Product Code, I've also just noticed the data set has dates like Mon (07/08) and also MON (07/08) meaning I'm getting 2 rows?

Comment: @VGJ those are questions that should go into a new post.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `groupby` + `sum` + `unstack`:

```
df.T.groupby([0, 1]).sum().unstack()   # [0, 1] are the column names here

              2            
1           Qty Sales Stock
0                          
Mon (07/08)   4     2     3
Tue (08/08)   6     4     5
```