# Transpose and Pivot with conditions

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I've got the following data set -

[image]

The issue with this data set is the cols F:J aren't consistent as you can see the days are upper case for 2 columns and lower case for the other. The desired output is below:

[image]

I did originally post this question in a different post but once I noticed the discrepancies I was advised to ask the question again in a new post -

[Best way to Pivot/Rotate Data Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47478559/best-way-to-pivot-rotate-data-set/47478694#47478694)

Comment: You can accept the previous answer firstly

Comment: Add df.rename(columns=str.upper) prior to other solutions